# Const Char * to Char array

Tags: string, casting

Why the statement below is correct even though the type of the string is const char *? As far as I know, the array must be const since I'm trying to type cast from const to non-const object but compilers accept that statement.

char s[] = "test";

Comment: In this context `"test"` is a literal string used as an initializer for the `char` array. The literal string is read-only, but the array where it gets copied during initialization does not have to be read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually just a special syntax for initializing an array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization

You can initialize a char array using a string literal, which is simply equivalent to declaring an array containing each of the characters in the string (including the null terminator).